# How can i make the left column to be static when user scroll to left?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

[image: f]

How can i make left column in the flex box to be static when the user scroll to left ?
the flexbox main div css below, and 4 boxes inside

```
.crsTable {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: check position;sticky

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: position sticky isn't helping

Comment: Try `position: fixed;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-left: 10;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: #569ca8;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> 
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="sticky">Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Company2</th>
        <th>Contact2</th>
        <th>Country2</th>
        <th>Company3</th>
        <th>Contact3</th>
        <th>Country3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>

        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="sticky">Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```